# Why won't my timezone changes be reflected in the date command?

Tags: linux, centos

I copied /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata to /etc/localtime. I also tried editing ZONE in /etc/sysconfig/clock but my default timezone is still CEST and not IST.

I already checked to make sure that a TZ variable isn't overriding it.

I've already googled it and found http://www.redhat.com/advice/tips/timezone.html and http://kezhong.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/change-timezone-on-centos-5-4/ but it didn't help.

I'm out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

```
[root@dhroid ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/clock 
ZONE="Asia/Kolkata"
UTC=false
ARC=false
[root@dhroid ~]$ ls -al /etc/localtime 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jul 19 16:10 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata
[root@dhroid ~]$ env | grep TZ
[root@dhroid ~]$ date
Tue Jul 19 16:11:52 CEST 2011
[root@dhroid ~]$
```

Comment: what about the daemons such as crond or syslog? when i change /etc/localtime or /etc/sysconfig/clock, the date and time showed in console changes really, but the logs for crontabs and messages mantains the past timestamp... it is necessary a reboot ...

Answer (score 7):

I have fixed the problem. There was nothing wrong with what I did. Everything was right the whole time. The issue was with the tzdata package, which was corrupted. As soon as I reinstalled the package from yum with `yum reinstall tzdata`, it worked!

Comment: All that you had to do is just run ``tzdata-update`` utility. This copies the correct zonefile to ``/etc/localtime``.

Answer (score 2):

after saving the changes to the file: '/etc/sysconfig/clock' a reboot is required for the changes in the timezone to take affect. Did you reboot your box after that ?

Comment: No, I haven't rebooted. But what about the /etc/localtime. When I worked with other systems (Fedora and Debian), I only needed to change /etc/localtime. I didn't need to do anything else.

Comment: # ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime  Exit from all sessions you are currently logged in and try rebooting your box. #date command will then show a updated time zone.

Comment: I'm not rebooting the system. There has to be a better solution. Other distros don't require a reboot for timezone changes.

Comment: Which distro are you using ? If it is a RedHat / Fedora / CentOS, then I am confident that a reboot is required for the changes to take place because there is something called hardware clock which should also sync with system timings and that will happen only after a reboot. That's what I suggest.

Comment: It is CentOS. Well my Fedora server didn't require a reboot and the change was applied immediately. The only difference is the CentOS is a VMware system and Fedora one is OpenVZ.

Comment: Just rebooted it and the timezone is still the same.

Comment: Ok got that, so check for the BIOS setting on VMware console; is the UTC time set to true ? Then edit /etc/sysconfig/clock and change UTC=true , if it is set to false then your configuration file looks fine. UTC in the configuration file must always reflect your BIOS settings.

Comment: I only have ssh access, so can't go into the BIOS. The issue is not with the time itself, but the timezone. Even if the time was wrong, it should still say IST, not CEST.

Comment: Oh!! Can you remove the symlink of /etc/localtime and just copy the zoneinfo by running the following command -> #cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime and run #date command now. What does it say ?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: I ran the same test on a CentOS VM that I have on my box. Copying /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata to /etc/localtime worked for me. I had my time zone set to UTC, but now it got over written and shows IST instead of EDT. Accept my answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: It hasn't solved my problem. My timezone is still set to CEST.

Comment: Run this command /sbin/hwclock –systohc and check

Comment: Again, the problem is not with the time but the TIMEZONE. The time zone says CEST.

Comment: Can you show me the contents of /etc/sysconfig/clock on your CentOS VM ? WELL, for the third time I did the following on my running CentOS VM : edited the file /etc/sysconfig/clock, Step (1) ZONE="Brazil/East" UTC=false ARC=false saved it and then Step (2) #cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/East /etc/localtime Step (3) #/sbin/hwclock --systohc Step (4) #date . That's it, I can see BRT timezone.

Comment: The contents are already shown in my question at the bottom.

Comment: Before I log off, I would suggest, try editing /etc/sysconfig/clock to some other time zone mentioned in /usr/share/zoneinfo directory and give a shot by doing what we have discussed earlier on this post so far. If that new time zone is reflected it's good for you, if not then there is something else happening which I am not aware of. Thanks !

Comment: Have tried already with Asia/Singapore and America/Chicago and it just doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer that worked for me here (Ubuntu 14.04+): [Timezone setting in Linux [closed]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110522/timezone-setting-in-linux)

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone Etc/UTC
```

I double checked with a reboot, it persists.  Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not 100% certain, but i believe that if you have /etc/sysconfig/clock configured with

UTC=false

then you aren't going to be able to dynamically change the timezone.

all of my machines are set with UTC true, and the local timezone as america/los_angeles. if i relink /etc/localtime to a different timezone, it's reflected in the 'date' command immediately.

if your system clock isn't locked to UTC, then the system doesn't know how to interpret a changed timezone, since they're all relative to UTC. only a reboot will reset its brain.

edit: so i think the bottom line is that until you've configured /etc/sysconfig/clock to UTC=true and rebooted (and reset your bios clock to utc) then you're stuck with that reboot.

Comment: I have asked my host company's technical support to

Comment: Turns out even support weren't able to find out what the problem is. I've tried with both settings, UTC set to true and false, and neither makes a difference. Support has suggested I reinstall the OS. I'm gonna do that as a last resort but I really want to find out why this is happening in the first place. I've not heard of anyone with this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this on Ubuntu recently. dhroid's answer gave me the hint I needed. Creating a new answer since the specific step was different on Ubuntu/Debian.
Typically I have been setting timezone with:

```
sudo mv /etc/localtime{,.bak}
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

Strangely that wasn't working so I tried to reconfigure tzdata:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Got this strange result:

```
Current default time zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
Local time is now:      Wed Jul  6 20:10:37 UTC 2016.
```

Reinstalling tzdata fixed it:
(apt-get install replaces existing package with latest)

```
sudo apt-get install tzdata

date
etc. PDT 2016
```